# Why induced exact sequence implies injectivity in question

Tags: exact-sequence

[image]

N is a module and M & L are submodules of N

I want to show that $\beta$ is injective but am having trouble understanding why the exact sequence above implies injectivity.

Comment: What is the kernel of the map $L \to \operatorname{Ker}(\beta)$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese since the image of previous morphism is identity then kernel of  $L \to \operatorname{Ker}(\beta)$ is _L_ ?

Comment: Ok I got it , thanks ,using factorisation theorem $0 \cong \operatorname{Ker}(\beta)
$